# Making changes to woocommerce order before save

Tags: wp-admin, woocommerce-offtopic

I use the hook woocommerce_before_calculate_totals to intercept and make changes to the cart before data is saved. Is there a hook or other way to do the same in the admin area? I need to evaluate the order details and make changes based on findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A popular method is to hook to the order status.

You have several status names to choose from:

1. completed
2. processing
3. cancelled
4. on-hold

You would use it like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing'
```

In addition you can intercept a certain change like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_completed'
```

Finally you can intercept any change that takes place like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed'
```

Comment: Very good, these are options. Love how many options there can be, I am using save_post as well.

Comment: Yes there are many more options. It all comes down to your specific scenario workflow.